# Order, sort or rank rows by group in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, rows

I have the following `df`

```
> df

A   1
B   2
B   2
C   1
D   2
D   2
E   1
F   2
F   2
```

`df = data.frame(Letters = LETTERS[1:6], Times = rep(c(1,2)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df = df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), df$Times),]`

But I would like to `reorder`/`sort`/`rank` (not sure what to use) my rows as follows:

```
> df

B   2
B   2
A   1
D   2
D   2
C   1
F   2
F   2
E   1
```

I have found answers to similar but yet different questions on SO. Still, none of them seems to solve mine.

Is there a way to do so in `BaseR`?

Comment: I want to adapt it to a bigger `df` where `letters` with number `1` are taxes and `letters` with number `2` total price and price without taxes. That is why, for example `B`, `D` and `F` are repeated twice.

Comment: if you want to decide the sequence manually, the easiest is to convert your column as factor, feeding your sequence to the `levels` argument, then sort it with your preferred method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option with `base R`

```
lvls <- c(do.call(rbind, with(unique(df), split(Letters, 
    factor(Times, levels = sort(unique(Times), decreasing = TRUE))))))
df[order(factor(df$Letters, levels = lvls)),]
#   Letters Times
#2       B     2
#3       B     2
#1       A     1
#5       D     2
#6       D     2
#4       C     1
#8       F     2
#9       F     2
#7       E     1
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Letters = c("A", "B", "B", "C", "D", "D", "E", 
"F", "F"), Times = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L)),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks... what in case there are repeated `Letters` and not only `unique`?

Comment: @Cahidora Can you update the post with an example (or post as a new question)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this follows your logic but it does agree with expected output,

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
 arrange(desc(Letters)) %>% 
 arrange(desc(cumsum(c(0, diff(Times) == 1))))

#  Letters Times
#1       B     2
#2       B     2
#3       A     1
#4       D     2
#5       D     2
#6       C     1
#7       F     2
#8       F     2
#9       E     1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way in base R using `split` with assumptions that `Times` argument would always be 1 or 2 and you'll have same number of unique `Letters` for both 1 and 2 values.

```
lst <- split(seq_len(nrow(df)), df$Letters)
df[unlist(c(rbind(lst[lengths(lst) == 2], lst[lengths(lst) == 1]))), ]

#  Letters Times
#2       B     2
#3       B     2
#1       A     1
#5       D     2
#6       D     2
#4       C     1
#8       F     2
#9       F     2
#7       E     1
```